# Format string - comma as float delimiter

Tags: ruby

```
printf("%.1f", 2.0)
```

This outputs 2.0, but I need 2,0.
Is there a way to format this for regions that use , as delimiter?
Without gsub or global settings though, as I can only access the format string in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in feature, but there are few methods in Active Support library

For example you can use [`ActiveSupport::NumberHelper`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb):

```rb
require "active_support/dependencies/autoload"
require "active_support/number_helper"

ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(0.2, separator: ",")
# => "0,2"
```

Or use Ruby core extension for [number conversions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb):

```rb
require "active_support/dependencies/autoload"
require "active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions"

0.2.to_fs(:delimited, separator: ",")
# => "0,2"
```

If you use I18n library and have YAML with [separators, delimeters, etc.](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml#L169-L175):

```rb
0.2.to_fs(:delimited, locale: :fr)
```

Comment: I‘m translating a game and only the `%.1f` part is exposed to me. So you say it is not possible just with that?

Comment: @Fox if `sprintf` is used under the hood and you can only edit the format string then no, you cannot specify the delimiter.